# Applications icon loading with glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to implement applications icon loading module. Module which will load application icon by package name.
Can anyone highlight proper way of implementation of custom GlideModule/ResourceDecoder and registering them in glide framework so, that **caching will work** for this icons?